# how to fix the size of the zoom in/ out image in iphone landscape?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator, cocos2d-iphone

pls provide me the logic of how to fix the size of the pintch in/out of image on the next page with the given image.eg....width=100 and height=150 then image is pintch in/ out upto that level and fix there if user is zoomed more then this size then also the image is fixed to that width ,height .

```
#import "PinchLibView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>



    @implementation PinchLibView

    @synthesize pinchImage;
    @synthesize pinchScrlView;
    @synthesize figureImageView;
    @synthesize getWidth,getHeight;



        -(void)initPinch{
            figureRect = self.frame;
         contentView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,
                                                                  figureRect.size.width, 
                                                                  figureRect.size.height)]; 
            pinchScrlView = [[CustomScrollView alloc]init];
            figureImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
            pinchScrlView.minimumZoomScale =1.0;
            pinchScrlView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
            //NSLog(@"%d %d",appDelegate.width1,appDelegate.height1);
            //getWidth=[appDelegate.width1 intValue];
            //getHeight=[appDelegate.height1 intValue];
            //NSLog(@"%d %d",getWidth,getHeight);
        }

        - (void)initScrollView{
            //figureImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
            self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            //figureImageView.image = pinchImage;
             figureImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

             pinchScrlView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 
                                             figureRect.size.width,  
                                             figureRect.size.height); 

            [pinchScrlView setResetFrame:figureRect];

            pinchScrlView.hidden = NO;
            pinchScrlView.zoomScale = 1.0;
            pinchScrlView.delegate = self;  
            pinchScrlView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
            pinchScrlView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;    

            figureImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,5,
                                               figureRect.size.width,figureRect.size.height-10); 

            [contentView addSubview:figureImageView];
            [pinchScrlView addSubview:contentView];

            [self addSubview:pinchScrlView];    


            CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
            animation.duration = 0.3f;
            animation.type = kCATransitionFade;

            pinchScrlView.zoomScale = 1.0;
            [pinchScrlView.layer addAnimation: animation forKey: nil];

            /*pinchScrlView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            figureImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];*/
            /*pinchScrlView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            figureImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; */

        }

        - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
                return contentView;
        }


        - (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale{

            /*  Reset Image if scale in less than   1.0     */
            if(scale <= 1.0){   

            UIEdgeInsets anEdgeInset = { 0, 0, 0, 0};
            pinchScrlView.contentInset = anEdgeInset;

            pinchScrlView.scrlFlag = FALSE;
            pinchScrlView.zoomScale = 0.0;

            pinchScrlView.scrollEnabled = NO;

            CATransition *animation = [ CATransition animation ];
            animation.duration = 0.3f;
            animation.type = kCATransitionFade;

            self.frame = figureRect;
            pinchScrlView.frame = figureRect;

            [self.layer addAnimation: animation forKey: nil ];
            [figureImageView.layer addAnimation: animation forKey: nil ];
            contentView.frame = figureRect; 
            pinchScrlView.contentSize = figureRect.size;
            contentView.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,
                                             self.frame.size.height/2);
            pinchScrlView.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,
                                               self.frame.size.height/2);
        }   

        /*  Make image centered if scale in greater than 1.0  */
        if(pinchScrlView.zoomScale > 1.0 && !pinchScrlView.scrlFlag){
             pinchScrlView.frame = self.superview.frame;

             self.frame =  self.superview.frame;
            pinchScrlView.clipsToBounds = NO;
            pinchScrlView.scrollEnabled = NO;
            pinchScrlView.contentSize = pinchScrlView.frame.size;   
            pinchScrlView.scrlFlag = TRUE;

            CGRect innerFrame =  contentView.frame;//////////
            CGRect scrollerBounds =pinchScrlView.bounds;
            //CGRect scrollerBounds =CGRectMake(50,50,appDelegate.width1,appDelegate.height1);
            if ( ( innerFrame.size.width < scrollerBounds.size.width ) || ( innerFrame.size.height < scrollerBounds.size.height ) )
            {
                CGFloat tempx = contentView.center.x - ( scrollerBounds.size.width / 2 );
                CGFloat tempy = contentView.center.y - ( scrollerBounds.size.height / 2 ); 
                CGPoint myScrollViewOffset = CGPointMake(tempx, tempy);

                pinchScrlView.contentOffset = myScrollViewOffset;
            }
            else if ((innerFrame.size.width > scrollerBounds.size.width) 
                     || (innerFrame.size.height > scrollerBounds.size.height)){
                if(innerFrame.size.width > scrollerBounds.size.width){
                    pinchScrlView.zoomScale =  self.frame.size.width/figureRect.size.width;
                }else if(innerFrame.size.height > scrollerBounds.size.height){
                    pinchScrlView.zoomScale =  self.frame.size.height/figureRect.size.height;
                }
                CGFloat tempx = contentView.center.x - (scrollerBounds.size.width / 2 );
                CGFloat tempy = contentView.center.y - (scrollerBounds.size.height / 2 );
                CGPoint myScrollViewOffset = CGPointMake( tempx, tempy);
                pinchScrlView.contentOffset = myScrollViewOffset;
            }   

            UIEdgeInsets anEdgeInset = { 0, 0, 0, 0};
            if(scrollerBounds.size.width > innerFrame.size.width)
            {
                anEdgeInset.left = (scrollerBounds.size.width - innerFrame.size.width) / 2;
                anEdgeInset.right = -anEdgeInset.left;   
            }
            if(scrollerBounds.size.height > innerFrame.size.height)
            {
                anEdgeInset.top = (scrollerBounds.size.height - innerFrame.size.height) / 2;
                anEdgeInset.bottom = -anEdgeInset.top;   
            }
            pinchScrlView.contentInset = anEdgeInset;
        }

        if(pinchScrlView.zoomScale > 1.0){
            CGRect innerFrame = contentView.frame;

            CGRect scrollerBounds =  pinchScrlView.bounds;
            //CGRect scrollerBounds =CGRectMake(50,50,appDelegate.width1,appDelegate.height1);

            if((innerFrame.size.width < scrollerBounds.size.width) 
               || (innerFrame.size.height < scrollerBounds.size.height)){

                CGFloat tempx = contentView.center.x - (scrollerBounds.size.width / 2 );
                CGFloat tempy = contentView.center.y - (scrollerBounds.size.height / 2 );
                CGPoint myScrollViewOffset = CGPointMake( tempx, tempy);
                pinchScrlView.contentOffset = myScrollViewOffset;
            }
            else if((innerFrame.size.width > scrollerBounds.size.width) 
                    || (innerFrame.size.height > scrollerBounds.size.height)){
                if(innerFrame.size.width > scrollerBounds.size.width){
                    pinchScrlView.zoomScale =  self.frame.size.width/figureRect.size.width;
                }else if(innerFrame.size.height > scrollerBounds.size.height){
                    pinchScrlView.zoomScale =  self.frame.size.height/figureRect.size.height;
                }
                CGFloat tempx = contentView.center.x - (scrollerBounds.size.width / 2 );
                CGFloat tempy = contentView.center.y - (scrollerBounds.size.height / 2 );
                CGPoint myScrollViewOffset = CGPointMake( tempx, tempy);
                pinchScrlView.contentOffset = myScrollViewOffset;
            }

            UIEdgeInsets anEdgeInset = { 0, 0, 0, 0};
            if (scrollerBounds.size.width > innerFrame.size.width){
                anEdgeInset.left = (scrollerBounds.size.width - innerFrame.size.width) / 2;
                anEdgeInset.right = -anEdgeInset.left; 
            }
            if (scrollerBounds.size.height > innerFrame.size.height){
                anEdgeInset.top = (scrollerBounds.size.height - innerFrame.size.height) / 2;
                anEdgeInset.bottom = -anEdgeInset.top; 
            }
            pinchScrlView.contentInset = anEdgeInset;
           }    
        }

        @end
```

Comment: Could be me being tired, but I can't understand your question. Could you please add punctuation?

Comment: just fixed the zoom in out of image upto fix widht and height so its like dynamic width and  height

Comment: HAI I AM HERE We just don't know what you're asking because your question doesn't make any sense at all. Comments like that do nothing to improve it, and everything to discourage people from even wanting to *try* to help you.

Comment: i want that image just zoom in  and out up to the fix width if user want to zoom more then this but its not possible and height given by the user eg. like 200 and 300 respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for pinch distance:

-(CGFloat) distanceBetweenTwoPoints:(CGPoint) fromPoint toPoint:(CGPoint) toPoint {
            float lengthX = fromPoint.x - toPoint.x;
            float lengthY = fromPoint.y - toPoint.Y;
            return sqrt((lengthX*lengthX) + (lengthY*lengthY));}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event {
     //---you figure out a way to detect double tap--
     //--records the distance made by the tow touches--
     originalDistance = [self distanceBetweenTwoPoints:touch1PT toPoint: touch2PT];}

//---fired when the user moved his finger(s) on the screen---
-(void) touchesMoved: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {

```
        //---you figure out a way to detect double tap--
        //---double-touch---
        //---get info of first touch---
        UITouch *touch1 = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

        //---get info of second touch---
        UITouch *touch2 = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];

        //---get the points touched---
        CGPoint touch1PT = [touch1 locationInView:[self view]];
        CGPoint touch2PT = [touch2 locationInView:[self view]];

        CGFloat currentDistance = [self distanceBetweenTwoPoints:touch1PT
                                                         toPoint:touch2PT];

        //---zoom in---
        if (currentDistance > originalDistance) {
            imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x - 2,
                                         imageView.frame.origin.y - 2,
                                         imageView.frame.size.width + 4,
                                         imageView.frame.size.height + 4);
        }
        else {
            //---zoom out---
            imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x + 2,
                                         imageView.frame.origin.y + 2,
                                         imageView.frame.size.width - 4,
                                         imageView.frame.size.height - 4);
        }
        originalDistance = currentDistance;}
```